# Can't use any of the polymer elements

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I've just started to learn and use polymer and I've made all the installations and imports as in Google's Polymer website but I still can't make a single polymer element to work. These are the files:
bower.json

```html
{
  "name": "take0",
  "description": "0.0",
  "main": "index.html",
  "moduleType": [
    "amd"
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "polymer"
  ],
  "authors": [
    "Balajee"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "core-component-page": "Polymer/core-component-page#^0.5",
    "core-elements": "Polymer/core-elements#^0.5.6",
    "paper-elements": "Polymer/paper-elements#^0.5.6",
    "platform": "Polymer/platform#^0.4.2",
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Take 0 on polymer
        </title>
      <link rel"import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
       <!-- Componenet kicks in-->
       <link   rel="import" href="components/component-one.html">
       </head>    
        <body>
            <component-one>
            </component-one>
        </body>
</html>
```

components/component-one.html:

```html
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<!-- Component one-->
<dom-module id="component-one">
  <style>
    paper-button.fancy {
      background: green;
      color: yellow;
    }
    paper-button.fancy:hover {
      background: lime;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <p>Ready to take you out with polymer!!</p>
    <paper-button raised>
      Click Me!!</paper-button>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "component-one",
    properties: {
      title: {
        type: String,
        value: "Hello World!!!"
      }
    },
    ready: function() {
      console.log("I'm Working!!!!!")
    }

  });
</script>
```

I've spent 2 days of looking for the problem and can't find anything that solves the issue.

Comment: I noticed that in your sample code here, the `link` tag which imports your component is not closed. That would stop your example from working.

Comment: Try to include Polymer.html in main index.html file before include polyfills `webcomponents` and then add your component. Also delete include tag for Polymer.html and script with polyfills  from your component. What browser you use? In console you have any errors?

Comment: Thanks for your instant response @Maria. I've closed that link tag but, nothing happens still.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry  I've made all the changes as said by Dimity but i still can't make the button work, I simply get the text saying "Click Me!!". And Dmitry, I use the latest build of chrome.

Comment: @Dmitry, Following are the errors I get in my console, Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'undefined'. The type name is invalid.
2polymer-micro.html:80 Uncaught TypeError: prototype.registerCallback is not a function
polymer-mixin.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Polymer.mixin is not a function
polymer-micro.html:71 Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'undefined'. The type name is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using Polymer 1.3.0 with elements build for the 'ancient' Polymer 0.5.

Try replacing the dependency part of your `bower.json` file with this one :

```
"dependencies": {
  "iron-component-page": "PolymerElements/iron-component-page#^1.0.0",
  "iron-elements": "PolymerElements/iron-elements#^1.0.0",
  "paper-elements": "PolymerElements/paper-elements#^1.0.0",
  "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.3.0"
}
```

You can see that the `core-elements` library is replaced by the `iron-elements`.

To avoid this kind of error, I recommend you to always use the Polymer Elements Catalog to find Google elements (For example here is [the paper-button page](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-button), use the recommended bower command displayed at the bottom of the menu drawer to import it).

Also, if you find an interesting element on Github or [customelements.io](http://www.customelements.io), always check it's `bower.json` to be certain of which Polymer version it is based on.

Comment: Thank you so much. My problem is solved. I'll take your feedback, to keep an eye on every json file for each element.